# Using a multi-dimensional array with a generic function

Tags: c, arrays, generic-programming

I've written the following generic function:

```
void* scramble(void* arr, int ElemSize, int n, int* indArr){
    void * res = malloc(n * ElemSize);
    int i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        memcpy((BYTE*)res+i*ElemSize, (BYTE*)arr+indArr[i]*ElemSize, ElemSize);

    return res;
}
```

The function gets an array, the size of each element, and number of elements in the array.
indArr is an array with indexes running from 0 to n-1 in any order.
The function returns a new array arranged according to indArr.
How can I use it to work with two dimensional arrays (or more)? I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
int indArr[] = {2, 0, 1};
char names[][10] = {{"David"}, {"Daniel"}, {"Joni"}};
char **res;

res = (char**)scramble(names, sizeof(char*), 3, indArr);

for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    printf("%s ", res[i]);
```

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`names` is an array of arrays.

The scrambler referrs to the outer array. The elements of the latter are the "strings". The size of each string is `10`.

So call the scrambler like this:

```
res = (char**)scramble(names, 10, 3, indArr);
```

or

```
res = (char**)scramble(names, sizeof(*names), 3, indArr);
```

---

**Update**:

To be able to access the single elements of the inner array do as follows:

```
char (*res)[10] = (char (*)[10]) scramble(names, sizeof(*names), 3, indArr);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  printf("res[%d] = '%s'\n", i, res[i]);
```

Comment: How do I print the strings from res? Will printf("%s", res[1]) do the trick? When I tried I didn't work

Comment: Could you care to explain what does (*res)[10] mean? @alk

Comment: @DavidTzoor: `char (*res)[10]` declares `res` to be a pointer to an array of 10 `char`s.